# RadTreeView horizontal auto scroll when expanding tree WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am using a RadTreeView control from telerik.

I am binding data to my tree using hierarchical data templates.

The data is displaying fine but when I programmatically expand all my items tree is scrolling horizontally right to the furthest point.

[image: scrolled to right]

I have tried hooking into the loaded event of the tree view and only enabling horizontal scrollbar after the expand all has been called but this doesn't work.

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rtv = sender as RadTreeView;

        if (rtv.ScrollViewer != null)
        {

            rtv.ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

            rtv.ExpandAll();

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("test"); //this causes desired behaviour.

            rtv.ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        }
    }
```

One thing I have noticed is if I add a call to show a messagebox after the expandall call the horizontal scroll bar is displayed scrolled to the left as required.

Is the messagebox causing the UI to fully refresh and expand before enabling the scrollbar?

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: May it be related to auto-scroll? I guess that the focus (during programmatically expanding) on expandable item can cause such behavior but MesssageBox intercepts it.

Comment: Yes the problem is exactly as you mentioned. When the tree is being expanded each expanded item is auto scrolled into view. The disabling of the horizontal scroll bar stops this from happening. The issue is that after the tree has expanded I want to re enable the horizontal scroll bar. The only way I have been able to successfully achieve this is by adding the messagebox.show

Comment: Idk how to solve problem completely, I think you should ask on Telerik forums (I have used their web-controls and saw a lot of bugs). But better workaround for you is to set scroll programmatically to left instead of showing message: rtv.ScrollViewer.ScrollInfo.SetHorizontalOffset(0);

Comment: I will double check but the problem is that after calling the expandall method it seems that the horizontal scroll offset is 0. so setting it back to 0 at this point has no effect. Its like the scrolling to the right is happening once execution switches back to the UI. Which I think is triggered sooner by the adition of the message box.